# Permissions API Call Failing when used in onOpen simple trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a Google Sheet with an Apps Script to do issue and task tracking. One of the features I'm trying to implement is permissions based assigning of tasks. As a precursor to that, I have a hidden sheet populated with a list of users and their file permissions, using code similar to that in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64203176/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-all-users-with-access-to-a-google-shared-drive-using-app/64225597#64225597)

When I manually run the code, it works fine. However, I want it to load every time the sheet is opened in case of new people entering the group or people leaving the group. So I made a call to my function in my onOpen simple trigger. However, when it is called via onOpen, I get the following:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.list failed with error: Login Required
> at getPermissionsList(MetaProject:382:33)
> at onOpen(MetaProject:44:3)

Here are my functions:

My onOpen Simple Trigger:

```
  function onOpen() {

  //Constant Definitions for this function
  const name_Access = 'ACCESS';
  const row_header = 1;
  const col_user = 1;
  const col_level = 2;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht_Access = ss.getSheetByName(name_Access);

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('MetaProject')
    .addSubMenu(
        ui.createMenu('View')
          .addItem('Restore Default Sheet View', 'restoreDefaultView')
          .addItem('Show All Sheets', 'showAllSheets')
        )
    .addSeparator()
    .addToUi();

  //Clear Contents, Leave Formatting
  sht_Access.clearContents();

  //Set Column Headers
  var head_name = sht_Access.getRange(row_header,col_user);
  var head_level = sht_Access.getRange(row_header,col_level);

  head_name.setValue('User');
  head_level.setValue('Level');

  //Refresh User List for use in this instance
  getPermissionsList();

}
```

Here is getPermissionsList:

```
function getPermissionsList() {

  const fileId = "<REDACTED>"; // ID of your shared drive
  const name_Sheet = 'ACCESS';
  const row_start = 2;
  const col_user = 1;
  const col_access = 2;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thissheet = ss.getSheetByName(name_Sheet);

  // THIS IS IMPORTANT! The default value is false, so the call won't 
  // work with shared drives unless you change this via optional arguments
  const args = {
    supportsAllDrives: true
  };

  // Use advanced service to get the permissions list for the shared drive
  let pList = Drive.Permissions.list(fileId, args);

  //Put email and role in an array
  let editors = pList.items;

  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
    let email = editors[i].emailAddress;
    let role = editors[i].role;

    //Populate columns with users and access levels / role
    thissheet.getRange(row_start + i,col_user).setValue(email);
    thissheet.getRange(row_start + i,col_access).setValue(role);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched before I posted and I found the answer via some related questions in the comments, but I didn't see one with an actual answer. The answer is, you cannot call for Permissions or anything requiring authorization from a Simple Trigger. You have to do an Installable trigger.

In order to do that do the following:

1. Create your function or rename it something other than "onOpen".

   NOTE: If you name it onOpen (as I originally did and posted in this answer) it WILL work, but you will actually run TWO triggers - both the installable trigger AND the simple trigger. The simple trigger will generate an error log, so a different name is recommended.
2. Click the clock (Triggers) icon on the left hand side in Apps Script.
3. Click "+ Add Trigger" in the lower right
4. Select the name of your function for "which function to run"
5. Select "onOpen" for "select event type"
6. Click "Save".

The exact same code I have above now runs fine.